# How to determine if ServletRequest is PreflightRequest?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, servlets, jetty

Title already says it, when i do an web-api call on my jetty servlet endpoint.

Is it enough to catch the

```
request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")
```

flag?

Or are there other possibilities to determine if the current request is of type preflight?

Answer (score 0):

Preflight requests are sent as `OPTIONS` so you can check for that, yes.

But depending on what you are doing (I'm assuming some CORS filter?) you might also want to check if the following headers are present on the preflight: `Access-Control-Request-Method` (what HTTP method will be used when the actual request is made) and `Access-Control-Request-Headers` (what HTTP headers will be used when the actual request is made).